# Application keeps running during debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug a java application through eclipse. I'm able to do this by starting my Tomcat server in Debug mode, and then the application breaks as expected at the breakpoints I have put. But after some 10-15 seconds, I can see the application continues to run even though it's supposed to be paused at the breakpoint. Is there any way to resolve this? I want the application to stand still at the breakpoint, and not continue until I debug forward line by line.

Answer (score 1):

By default breakpoints suspend the thread.

If you want to fully suspend your application, you can switch to **"Suspend VM"** in breakpoint properties:

[image: Breakpoint properties]

Comment: Tried that. Still doesn't work. The application holds for some 10 seconds, and then continues to run